# Lindström's theorem, are there any other maximal elements?

Tags: first-order-logic

Lindström's theorem says that first order logic is the strongest logic that follows compactness and Löwenheim–Skolem. By strongest it means it is a maximal element under the ordering of A$\leq$B when B can model anything A can.
So there could be some other logic that is also maximal, is any such logic known, or is it suspected that none exist?

Comment: Would you add a reference to what you are calling Lindström's theorem?  I'd be interested to see a formal definition of what a "logic" is and how the relation "B can model anything A can" is grounded in that definition.

Comment: @hardmath: [This PDF](http://www.math.helsinki.fi/logic/opetus/lt/lindstrom_theorem1.pdf) seems to be a decent introduction.